# How to make glyph-icon to come ajax link text in Razor?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the bellow code for sorting one column. The glyphicon I have added is not clickable. I want same click event on action link test as well as glyphicon.When I am including the glyphicon class inside the action link the glyphicon is appearing before the action link text.

```
<div>
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Project Name", "ListView",
                   new AjaxOptions()
                   {
                       HttpMethod = "GET",
                       UpdateTargetId = "MyProject",
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                       OnSuccess = "HightlightSelectedProjectTab(" + ViewBag.ProjectType + ")",
                   }, new { Class = "linkth" })
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like this (tested it with font awesome icons and it's working):

```
<div>
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Project Name", "ListView",
                   new AjaxOptions()
                   {
                       HttpMethod = "GET",
                       UpdateTargetId = "MyProject",
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                       OnSuccess = "HightlightSelectedProjectTab(" + ViewBag.ProjectType + ")",
                   }, new { Class = "linkth glyphicon glyphicon-sort" })
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly how glyphicon should be used. It will be `<a><span glyphicon>Project Name</span></a>` while it should be `<a><span glyphicon></span>Project Name</a>`.

Comment: In case html it will work I think but In case of Razor ..?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Actually the glyphicon class will be added directly to the <a> tag.

Comment: @Zippy Oh, yes, of course, I meant `<a glyphicon>ProjectName</a>` :)